# how to enforce upper case only results from alternation using EditPad Pro 7

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
\b(JIN|DIN|CIN|PIN|JCN|DCN|CCN)\d{6}\b
```

which correctly catches: `JIN123456, DIN789012, CIN345678, etc`

But annoyingly it also catches 'din017899'
How can i prevent it from catching 'din123456' i.e. when the 'din' part is in lower case? 
I want it to catch DIN, CIN etc only when they are upper case.

`\b(JIN|DIN|CIN|PIN|JCN|DCN|CCN)(?!=/^[^a-z]*$/)\d{6}\b` and countless other attempts have failed.

Comment: Did you used the `i` flag (ignore case)?

Comment: I would recommend you add the tag "editpad" since your question refers to EditPad Pro 7

Answer (score 0):

When you use search option, select `regex` and `case`:

[image]

and it should work.